lemnoslife endpoint does not work for getting the comment likes
I'm using yt.lemnoslife.com to get the likes of a group of comments.
Sometimes, the response works, but, for example, with this video: vDTHkPbFwkk - it returns "Invalid id" - despite the fact that both the video and the comment does exists.
URL: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&id=Ugyg08gvNzYt-VIu09t4AaABAg.9eMk47vaWpQ9eN6G-nAILq&videoId=vDTHkPbFwkk
Response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid id"
    }
}

With this URL, it works:
URL: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&id=UgzKbLo742tGc4QMv5N4AaABAg&videoId=cFl1FXcG_sE
Response:
{
    "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 235,
        "resultsPerPage": 20
    },
    "nextPageToken": "Eg0SC2NGbDFGWGNHX3NFGAYy1QIKqwJnZXRfcmFua2VkX3N0cmVhbXMtLUNxVUJDSUFFRlJlMzBUZ2FtZ0VLbFFFSTJGOFFnQVFZQnlLS0FadnRDWVV0N1NSUm1ZZ1N5V2tWd0NyR29TZS1Ea21TeXNZbXl1SVM0QmkzQUpoN3lUbENkSEpCemllLXdJV0M5RkxkVEF4T0NiYmZ3QlpDNW44M1AzbkszbS1qaVFKelZxS2lSUXNaUG1HNGQwb2cwMXNVWFBSVDh5UzNtb0twWkl3RmxJOUF0ZDFQRVVSR0I0UzhTR01QSi1fZnIyY2F2a3RTZFlpQ2o0bVJpbkdvbTRHaS1vdzFJQkFVRWdVSXFDQVlBQklIQ0lVZ0VCUVlBUklGQ0lrZ0dBQVNCd2lJSUJBQkdBQVNCUWlISUJnQUdBQSIRIgtjRmwxRlhjR19zRTAAeAEoFEIQY29tbWVudHMtc2VjdGlvbg%3D%3D",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UgzKbLo742tGc4QMv5N4AaABAg",
            "snippet": {
                "topLevelComment": {
                    "kind": "youtube#comment",
                    "etag": "NotImplemented",
                    "id": "UgzKbLo742tGc4QMv5N4AaABAg",
                    "snippet": {
                        "content": "Algo o alguien se llevó el cadáver...o el cadáver se levantó solo?\nQuedé confundido en esa parte.\nBuen relato, Conejo Negro ",
                        "publishedAt": "2 years ago",
                        "wasEdited": false,
                        "authorChannelId": "UCbi-ro_sIMWsF4ic_zykpFA",
                        "authorHandle": "@marcoaureliofernandezreyes1413",
                        "authorName": "Alguien te observa en la oscuridad",
                        "authorAvatar": {
                            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AIdro_nK0y2BR4xPgqCr6r30Y75NerHFIIwlh7ppDTv77Kc=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                            "width": 88,
                            "height": 88
                        },
                        "isCreator": false,
                        "isArtist": false,
                        "likeCount": 1,
                        "totalReplyCount": 0,
                        "videoCreatorHasReplied": false,
                        "isPinned": false,
                        "creatorHeart": false,
                        "nextPageToken": null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        [...]
}


Opening an issue on https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues would be more appropriate, but anyway I am investigating your issue. It just seems that comments answering other comments are not supported, I am adding the support.

The issue should now be solved thanks to commit 11566147f4d54b8d8d8481709fd5bf6b1329f4de

@BenjaminLoison Thank you. I'll continue the issue on the linked github. I'm not sure if you can post your answer and I'll accept it.

Side note: you could also consider create a tag for group questions related to your API.

I am not sure if it is well with Stack Overflow rules for me to post my comment as an answer, so I will not do so.

Thanks for the notice about the tag creation, I opened accordingly issues/302.

For reference you posted an issue on the repository issues/303.
